# Show that the quotient $X/Y$ has the Cauchy distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem with which I'm struggling for a while.

> Suppose that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent
>   and that each has the standard normal distribution.
>   Show that the quotient $X/Y$ has the Cauchy distribution.

I know how to solve it by Jacobian and multivariable transformation but I tried to do this a different way and I can't spot a mistake but my answer gives a contradiction.

My solution: Let $G$ be the cdf of $X/Y $, then

\begin{align*}
G(c)
&= \mathbb{P}(X/Y \leq c) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X/Y \leq c \mid Y > 0)\mathbb{P}(Y > 0) + \mathbb{P}(X/Y \leq c \mid Y < 0)\mathbb{P}(Y < 0) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \big[ \mathbb{P}(X/Y \leq c \mid Y > 0) + \mathbb{P}(X/Y \leq c \mid Y < 0) \big] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \big[ \mathbb{P}(X \leq cY) + \mathbb{P}(X \geq cY) \big] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Why did you drop conditioning in the last line?

Comment: Because i used fact that either Y>0 or Y<0 in multiplying inequalities both sides by Y

Comment: Now i see that thats probably the mistake

Comment: For instance, you may check that $\mathbf{P}(X\leq Y) = \frac{1}{2}$ while $\mathbf{P}(X \leq Y \mid Y > 0) = \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: $$ \begin{align}
& \frac 1 2 \big[ \Pr(X/Y \leq c \mid Y > 0) + \Pr(X/Y \leq c \mid Y < 0) \big] \\ \\
= {} & \frac 1 2 \big[ \Pr(X \leq cY\mid Y>0) + \Pr(X \geq cY\mid Y<0) \big] \\ {}
\end{align} $$
Should $\Pr(X\le cY\mid Y>0)$ be the same as $\Pr(X\le cY) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Using independence of X and Y, $G(c) =\int_{-\infty}^0 f(y)dy\int_{cy}^{\infty}f(x)dx+\int_0^{\infty}f(y)dy\int_{-\infty}^{cy}f(x)dx$.  You effectively tried to switch the order of integration without taking into account the difference in endpoints for the x integration.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from my comment.  $$G(c)=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{cy}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}dxdy+\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{cy}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}dxdy).$$  Change to polar coordinates and get $$G(c)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}e^-\frac{r^2}{2}rdr\left(\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\arctan(c)}+\int_{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\arctan(c)}\right)d\theta=\frac{2\arctan(c)+\pi}{2\pi}.$$ When we take the derivative with respect to c we get the density function for the Cauchy distribution $G'(c)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+c^2}$.

Comment: In the above derivation, when I switched to polar coordinates, I interchanged the x and y axes, since x=cy.